# Advice on accesing internet connection

Tags: java, android, static-methods

I am actually using below code to check internet connection for android app

ConnectionDetector.java

```
package com.example.detectinternetconnection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

And method called for is :

```
ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
```

But,
Recently someone adviced me saying to use this and am not convinced at all to use. Need help from you all brilliant people,  suggest whether i have  written wrong code?
Advised code to use for me :

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

    public static  boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) applicationcontext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

Code to be using like this

```
if(ConnectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet){
     // true and code 
}
```

Please let me know whats is the difference ??
Whether object defining with the context  is a bad idea or using static method of class ??

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is not wrong. However, the suggested replacement is slightly better because it's easier to use. As you can see for yourself, your original code requires two lines to create an object and call the checking method, and the replacement is just one line (one method call).

Comment: Whether static reference is better approach than object creation ??

Comment: An object creation is better when the object exists for a longer time, and multiple operations are performed with it.

Comment: Don't you think static reference will be live till app run on device . It will heavily fit on memory spot and whether static method has any end or garbage collected anytime ??

Comment: If i have N number of places where am using existing object in a single class will it be better or N number of times accesing static method at all places ? What do you say about this approach

Comment: In this case, using a static method will use less memory, because the ConnectionDetector object will not need to be allocated. You only need to worry about long-term memory usage if the class has static _fields_, which is not the case here.